# Does the image of a unitary irrep span all unitary operators?

Tags: operator-theory, representation-theory, hilbert-spaces, lie-groups

Consider an irreducible unitary representation $\rho: SE_3 \to U$ where $SE_3 = \mathbb{R}^3 \rtimes SO(3)$ is the (special) Euclidean group and $U$ is the (infinite dimensional) Lie group of unitary operators on the Hilbert space $L^2(S^2)$ where $S^2$ is the 2-sphere.

I am interested in the generalization of Burnside's theorem ([If $(\pi,V)$ is irreducible, then $\pi(G)$ spans $\operatorname{End}(V)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3176651/if-pi-v-is-irreducible-then-pig-spans-operatornameendv)) from finite dim irreps to infinite dim irreps . In other words, is it true that the image $\rho(SE_3)$ "spans" $U$ in the sense that we can write any element in $U$ as a linear combination of elements from $\rho(SE_3)$?

Related: [Is this a basis for the bounded operators on $ L^2(\mathbb{R}) $?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4303824/is-this-a-basis-for-the-bounded-operators-on-l2-mathbbr)