# Center of a group and faithful unitary irreps

Tags: functional-analysis, representation-theory

If a group $ G $ admits a faithful irreducible finite dimensional complex representation $ \pi: G \to GL_n(\mathbb{C}) $ then the algebra generated by $ \pi(G) $ is all of $ M_n(\mathbb{C}) $. So in particular the center of $ G $ must be contained in the center of the full matrix algebra, which is the diagonal copy of $ \mathbb{C}^* $ , $ \mathbb{C}^* I $. See

[If $(\pi,V)$ is irreducible, then $\pi(G)$ spans $\operatorname{End}(V)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3176651/if-pi-v-is-irreducible-then-pig-spans-operatornameendv)

If, moreover, $ G $ admits a faithful irreducible finite dimensional unitary representation (which is equivalent to the original hypothesis together with $ G $ being compact) then the center of $ G $ must be contained in the diagonal copy of $ U_1 $.

What happens if we drop the hypothesis of finite dimensionality? If a Lie group $ G $ admits a faithful unitary irrep can we still conclude that the center of $ G $ is isomorphic to a closed subgroup of $ U_1 $?

Comment: Consider nilpotent Lie groups.

Comment: @markvs could you perhaps expand on that thought?

Comment: Compactness is assumed?

Comment: No I didn't assume compactness ( although I'm always especially interested in the compact case). It's just what the question says. "If a Lie group $ G $ admits a faithful unitary irrep can we still conclude that the center of $ G $ is isomorphic to a closed subgroup of $ U_1 $?"

Comment: Then take the direct product of two Heisenberg  groups.

Comment: ok that sounds like the kind of counterexample I was expecting. Could you say a little more about that? I see an obvious way to make a faithful unitary representation and an obvious way to make a unitary irreducible representation but I'm not sure how to make one that is faithful unitary and irreducible.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_group#Representation_theory

Comment: I'm aware of the schrodinger representation but the obvious thing to do is take a direct sum of two schrodinger representations but that's not irreducible. Are you suggesting something like take both schrodinger representations on the same hilbert space but then scale one by some other function so the rep is still faithful? It's not clear to me how to get a representation of the product that is simultaneously faithful and irreducible

Comment: I would take the tensor product instead of direct sum. But I have not thought about it.